# Use multiple interpolation methods in time series python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, interpolation

I am using a dataset of daily river level of hydrometric stations from 1980 to 2020. I want to use linear interpolation to fill the missing values from November to July and use polynomial interpolation from July to November.

Here is a sample for 1980:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

nan = np.nan

from pandas import Timestamp
data = {
    Timestamp('1980-01-01 00:00:00'): 0.847000003,
    Timestamp('1980-01-02 00:00:00'): 0.797999978,
    Timestamp('1980-01-03 00:00:00'): 0.783999979,
    Timestamp('1980-01-04 00:00:00'): 0.744000018,
    Timestamp('1980-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.731000006,
    Timestamp('1980-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.685000002,
    Timestamp('1980-01-07 00:00:00'): 0.638999999,
    Timestamp('1980-01-08 00:00:00'): 0.632000029,
    Timestamp('1980-01-09 00:00:00'): 0.632000029,
    Timestamp('1980-01-10 00:00:00'): 0.625999987,
    Timestamp('1980-01-11 00:00:00'): 0.586000025,
    Timestamp('1980-01-12 00:00:00'): 0.574999988,
    Timestamp('1980-01-13 00:00:00'): 0.545000017,
    Timestamp('1980-01-14 00:00:00'): 0.529999971,
    Timestamp('1980-01-15 00:00:00'): 0.474999994,
    Timestamp('1980-01-16 00:00:00'): 0.49000001,
    Timestamp('1980-01-17 00:00:00'): 0.465000004,
    Timestamp('1980-01-18 00:00:00'): 0.456,
    Timestamp('1980-01-19 00:00:00'): 0.430999994,
    Timestamp('1980-01-20 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-21 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-22 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-23 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-24 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-25 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-26 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-27 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-28 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-29 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-30 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-01-31 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-02-01 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-02-02 00:00:00'): 0.25,
    Timestamp('1980-02-03 00:00:00'): 0.230000004,
    Timestamp('1980-02-04 00:00:00'): 0.209999993,
    Timestamp('1980-02-05 00:00:00'): 0.189999998,
    Timestamp('1980-02-06 00:00:00'): 0.172000006,
    Timestamp('1980-02-07 00:00:00'): 0.153999999,
    Timestamp('1980-02-08 00:00:00'): 0.137999997,
    Timestamp('1980-02-09 00:00:00'): 0.134000003,
    Timestamp('1980-02-10 00:00:00'): 0.119999997,
    Timestamp('1980-02-11 00:00:00'): 0.115999997,
    Timestamp('1980-02-12 00:00:00'): 0.101999998,
    Timestamp('1980-02-13 00:00:00'): 0.097999997,
    Timestamp('1980-02-14 00:00:00'): 0.083999999,
    Timestamp('1980-02-15 00:00:00'): 0.079999998,
    Timestamp('1980-02-16 00:00:00'): 0.064000003,
    Timestamp('1980-02-17 00:00:00'): 0.048999999,
    Timestamp('1980-02-18 00:00:00'): 0.039000001,
    Timestamp('1980-02-19 00:00:00'): 0.029999999,
    Timestamp('1980-02-20 00:00:00'): 0.029999999,
    Timestamp('1980-02-21 00:00:00'): 0.022,
    Timestamp('1980-02-22 00:00:00'): 0.015,
    Timestamp('1980-02-23 00:00:00'): 0.008,
    Timestamp('1980-02-24 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-02-25 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-02-26 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-02-27 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-02-28 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-02-29 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-01 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-02 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-03 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-04 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-05 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-06 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-07 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-08 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-09 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-10 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-11 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-12 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-13 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-14 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-15 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-16 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-17 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-18 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-19 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-20 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-21 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-22 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-03-23 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-03-24 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-03-25 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-03-26 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-03-27 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-03-28 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-03-29 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-03-30 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-03-31 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-01 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-02 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-03 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-04 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-05 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-06 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-07 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-08 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-09 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-04-10 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-11 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-12 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-13 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-14 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-15 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-16 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-17 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-18 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-19 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-20 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-21 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-22 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-23 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-24 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-25 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-26 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-27 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-28 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-29 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-04-30 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-01 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-02 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-03 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-04 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-05 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-06 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-07 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-08 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-09 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-10 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-11 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-12 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-13 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-14 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-15 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-16 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-17 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-18 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-19 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-05-20 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-21 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-22 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-23 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-24 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-25 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-26 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-27 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-28 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-29 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-30 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-05-31 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-06-01 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-06-02 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-06-03 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-06-04 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-06-05 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-06 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-07 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-08 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-09 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-10 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-11 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-12 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-13 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-14 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-15 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-16 00:00:00'): 0.0,
    Timestamp('1980-06-17 00:00:00'): 0.001,
    Timestamp('1980-06-18 00:00:00'): 0.335999995,
    Timestamp('1980-06-19 00:00:00'): 1.159000039,
    Timestamp('1980-06-20 00:00:00'): 2.006999969,
    Timestamp('1980-06-21 00:00:00'): 1.898000002,
    Timestamp('1980-06-22 00:00:00'): 1.804999948,
    Timestamp('1980-06-23 00:00:00'): 1.654999971,
    Timestamp('1980-06-24 00:00:00'): 1.644999981,
    Timestamp('1980-06-25 00:00:00'): 1.644999981,
    Timestamp('1980-06-26 00:00:00'): 1.621999979,
    Timestamp('1980-06-27 00:00:00'): 1.276000023,
    Timestamp('1980-06-28 00:00:00'): 1.003000021,
    Timestamp('1980-06-29 00:00:00'): 0.920000017,
    Timestamp('1980-06-30 00:00:00'): 0.851999998,
    Timestamp('1980-07-01 00:00:00'): 0.718999982,
    Timestamp('1980-07-02 00:00:00'): 0.657999992,
    Timestamp('1980-07-03 00:00:00'): 0.603999972,
    Timestamp('1980-07-04 00:00:00'): 0.518000007,
    Timestamp('1980-07-05 00:00:00'): 0.432000011,
    Timestamp('1980-07-06 00:00:00'): 0.426999986,
    Timestamp('1980-07-07 00:00:00'): 0.426999986,
    Timestamp('1980-07-08 00:00:00'): 0.426999986,
    Timestamp('1980-07-09 00:00:00'): 0.426999986,
    Timestamp('1980-07-10 00:00:00'): 0.409999996,
    Timestamp('1980-07-11 00:00:00'): 0.393000007,
    Timestamp('1980-07-12 00:00:00'): 0.393000007,
    Timestamp('1980-07-13 00:00:00'): 0.393000007,
    Timestamp('1980-07-14 00:00:00'): 0.375999987,
    Timestamp('1980-07-15 00:00:00'): 0.34799999,
    Timestamp('1980-07-16 00:00:00'): 0.324999988,
    Timestamp('1980-07-17 00:00:00'): 0.312000006,
    Timestamp('1980-07-18 00:00:00'): 0.291000009,
    Timestamp('1980-07-19 00:00:00'): 0.291000009,
    Timestamp('1980-07-20 00:00:00'): 0.324000001,
    Timestamp('1980-07-21 00:00:00'): 0.354999989,
    Timestamp('1980-07-22 00:00:00'): 0.764999986,
    Timestamp('1980-07-23 00:00:00'): 2.266000032,
    Timestamp('1980-07-24 00:00:00'): 2.410000086,
    Timestamp('1980-07-25 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-07-26 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-07-27 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-07-28 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-07-29 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-07-30 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-07-31 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-01 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-02 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-03 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-04 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-05 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-06 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-07 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-08 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-09 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-10 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-11 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-12 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-13 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-14 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-15 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-16 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-17 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-18 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-19 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-20 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-21 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-22 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-23 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-08-24 00:00:00'): 216.6999969,
    Timestamp('1980-08-25 00:00:00'): 264.1000061,
    Timestamp('1980-08-26 00:00:00'): 299.3999939,
    Timestamp('1980-08-27 00:00:00'): 280.8999939,
    Timestamp('1980-08-28 00:00:00'): 211.1000061,
    Timestamp('1980-08-29 00:00:00'): 194.1999969,
    Timestamp('1980-08-30 00:00:00'): 189.0,
    Timestamp('1980-08-31 00:00:00'): 191.6999969,
    Timestamp('1980-09-01 00:00:00'): 200.1999969,
    Timestamp('1980-09-02 00:00:00'): 235.3999939,
    Timestamp('1980-09-03 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-04 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-05 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-06 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-07 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-08 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-09 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-10 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-11 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-12 00:00:00'): 241.1999969,
    Timestamp('1980-09-13 00:00:00'): 242.3000031,
    Timestamp('1980-09-14 00:00:00'): 232.1000061,
    Timestamp('1980-09-15 00:00:00'): 223.3000031,
    Timestamp('1980-09-16 00:00:00'): 202.5,
    Timestamp('1980-09-17 00:00:00'): 176.5,
    Timestamp('1980-09-18 00:00:00'): 177.8000031,
    Timestamp('1980-09-19 00:00:00'): 178.5,
    Timestamp('1980-09-20 00:00:00'): 169.1999969,
    Timestamp('1980-09-21 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-22 00:00:00'): 118.1999969,
    Timestamp('1980-09-23 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-24 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-25 00:00:00'): 177.3999939,
    Timestamp('1980-09-26 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-27 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-28 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-29 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-09-30 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-01 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-02 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-03 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-04 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-05 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-06 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-07 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-08 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-09 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-10 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-11 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-12 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-13 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-14 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-15 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-16 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-17 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-18 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-19 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-20 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-21 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-22 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-23 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-24 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-25 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-26 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-27 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-28 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-29 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-30 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-10-31 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-01 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-02 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-03 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-04 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-05 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-06 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-07 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-08 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-09 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-10 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-11 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-12 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-13 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-14 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-15 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-16 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-17 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-18 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-19 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-20 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-21 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-22 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-23 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-24 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-25 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-26 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-27 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-28 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-29 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-11-30 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-12-01 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-12-02 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-12-03 00:00:00'): nan,
    Timestamp('1980-12-04 00:00:00'): 2.230000019,
    Timestamp('1980-12-05 00:00:00'): 2.141000032,
    Timestamp('1980-12-06 00:00:00'): 2.058000088,
    Timestamp('1980-12-07 00:00:00'): 1.975000024,
    Timestamp('1980-12-08 00:00:00'): 1.893000007,
    Timestamp('1980-12-09 00:00:00'): 1.722000003,
    Timestamp('1980-12-10 00:00:00'): 1.447000027,
    Timestamp('1980-12-11 00:00:00'): 1.274000049,
    Timestamp('1980-12-12 00:00:00'): 1.200000048,
    Timestamp('1980-12-13 00:00:00'): 1.129999995,
    Timestamp('1980-12-14 00:00:00'): 1.055999994,
    Timestamp('1980-12-15 00:00:00'): 0.92900002,
    Timestamp('1980-12-16 00:00:00'): 0.916999996,
    Timestamp('1980-12-17 00:00:00'): 0.865999997,
    Timestamp('1980-12-18 00:00:00'): 0.847000003,
    Timestamp('1980-12-19 00:00:00'): 0.791999996,
    Timestamp('1980-12-20 00:00:00'): 0.737999976,
    Timestamp('1980-12-21 00:00:00'): 0.685000002,
    Timestamp('1980-12-22 00:00:00'): 0.632000029,
    Timestamp('1980-12-23 00:00:00'): 0.582000017,
    Timestamp('1980-12-24 00:00:00'): 0.540000021,
    Timestamp('1980-12-25 00:00:00'): 0.504999995,
    Timestamp('1980-12-26 00:00:00'): 0.495000005,
    Timestamp('1980-12-27 00:00:00'): 0.465000004,
    Timestamp('1980-12-28 00:00:00'): 0.456,
    Timestamp('1980-12-29 00:00:00'): 0.430999994,
    Timestamp('1980-12-30 00:00:00'): 0.426999986,
    Timestamp('1980-12-31 00:00:00'): 0.426
}
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['Hydro'])

df.plot()
```

Here is the original dataframe:

[image]

The interpolation I want in red:

[image]